# How to display Current & Previous Month Name along with Total of Current Revenue per month & Total of Previous Revenue per month through SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

**[Revenue Raw Data]** consisting of **Month_ID,Revenue**

and it has the following sample data:

```
Month_ID 
128      
124
123
122
126
120

Revenue
1768077
1767617
1734230
1687976
1686309
```

**yt_Calendar_lookup** consisting of **Month_ID,Month_No,Month_Name**

and it has the following sample data:

```
Month_No
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

Month_ID
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131

Month_Name
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the results for the following **5 columns**:

1. Display **Current Month** as the **first column** from the table **yt_Calendar_lookup**
2. Display **Total Revenue for the Current Month** as the **second column** from the table **[Revenue Raw Data]**
3. Display **Previous Month** as the **third column** from the table **yt_Calendar_lookup**
4. Display **Total Revenue for the Previous Month** as the **fourth column** from the table **[Revenue Raw Data]**
5. Display **Revenue difference between Current Month and Previous Month** as the **fifth column** from the table **[Revenue Raw Data]**

Initially, this is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    A.[Total Revenue for Current Month]
    , B.[Total Revenue for Previous Month]
    , A.[Total Revenue for current Month] - B.[Total Revenue for previous Month] AS 'Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month'
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS 'Total Revenue for Current Month' 
    FROM [Revenue Raw Data]
    WHERE Month_ID IN (SELECT MAX(Month_ID) FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
) A, (
    SELECT SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS 'Total Revenue for Previous Month'
    FROM [Revenue Raw Data]
    WHERE Month_ID IN (SELECT MAX(Month_ID) - 1 FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
) B
```

With the query above, I could successfully display the following **3 columns**:

**Total Revenue for Current Month, Total Revenue for Previous Month, Revenue Difference between Current Month and Previous Month**

And this is the result I have received:

```
Total Revenue for Current Month Total Revenue for Previous Month
21221564                        19973825

Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month
1247739
```

With the next query, I was trying to display the following **5 columns**:

**Current Month, Total Revenue for Current Month, Previous Month, Total Revenue for Previous Month, Revenue Difference between Current Month and Previous Month**

This is what I have tried:

```
    SELECT A.[Current Month], 
A.[Total Revenue for Current Month], 
    B.[Previous Month], 
B.[Total Revenue for Previous Month],
    A.[Total Revenue for current Month] - B.[Total Revenue for previous Month] 
    AS 'Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month'
    FROM
    (SELECT Month_Name 
AS 'Current Month', 
    SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) 
    AS 'Total Revenue for Current Month' 
    FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
    WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
    AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN 
    (SELECT MAX(Month_ID) FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
    ) A,
    (SELECT Month_Name 
AS 'Previous Month', 
    SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) 
    AS 'Total Revenue for Previous Month'
    FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
    WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
    AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN 
(SELECT MAX(Month_ID) - 1 FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
    ) B
```

I received the following error message:

> Column 'yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I even tried by adding **GROUP BY A.Month_Name,B.Month_Name**, and even after that I am receiving the same error message.

I am still trying to figure out on where I am making the mistake for this particular query.

Solution for this particular issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the painful formatting you have some really bad habits going on here. Aliases like A, B are worthless as they actually make it harder to work with because you have to constantly go search for what that alias means. You also are using antiquated join syntax. ANSI-92 style joins are now 30 years old, time to update your syntax. What would really help with your question is sample data and desired output.

Comment: @DaleK I have added the sample data and desired results as you have requested.

Comment: In your first sample data there are 6 month_ids and 5 revenues. It would be nice if you can give the data in a tabular format as we are talking about tables here. Also, what will be the previous month in case current month is january?

Comment: @Dale K
I have revisited old questions and accepted answers as you have suggested.

Comment: Optional, but if you provide your sample data as a [mre] i.e. either a DBFiddle or as DDL+DML so that people can copy + paste + run your example directly you make it much easier for them.

Comment: @ Dale K 
I actually imported the tables from Excel File to SQL Server Management Studio.
Would it be OK if I send the Excel files ?
I do have the links for the Excel files as well.

Comment: No, that doesn't make it easier for anyone... a DBFiddle is the way to go. And as already suggested, improving the layout of your queries will make it much easier for people to try and work out what is going on.

Comment: @Dale K  I have made changes to the query layouts. I hope it is much more readable now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Another bad habit: using `''` to quote column names, you should use `[]` instead

Comment: @Dale K - I have made changes to the second query layout as you have suggested. Hope I could do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to add `GROUP BY Month_Name` to the 2 sub-queries.

```
SELECT 
  C.[Current Month], 
  C.[Total Revenue for Current Month], 
  P.[Previous Month], 
  P.[Total Revenue for Previous Month],
  C.[Total Revenue for current Month] - P.[Total Revenue for previous Month] 
    AS [Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month] 
 FROM
 (
   SELECT Month_Name AS [Current Month], 
    SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS [Total Revenue for Current Month] 
   FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
   WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
     AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN (
           SELECT MAX(Month_ID) 
           FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
   GROUP BY Month_Name
) C
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT Month_Name AS [Previous Month], 
   SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS [Total Revenue for Previous Month] 
  FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
  WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
    AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN (
          SELECT MAX(Month_ID) - 1 
          FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
  GROUP BY Month_Name
) P;
```

But this can also be calculated via conditional aggregation.

```
WITH CTE_MONTHS AS (
  SELECT TOP 2 
    Month_ID
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Month_ID DESC) AS rn
  FROM [Revenue Raw Data]
  GROUP BY Month_ID
  ORDER BY Month_ID DESC
)
SELECT 
  Month1 AS [Current Month]
, Revenue1 AS [Total Revenue for Current Month] 
, Month2 AS [Previous Month] 
, Revenue2 AS [Total Revenue for Previous Month] 
, Revenue1 - Revenue2 AS [Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month] 
FROM
(
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.rn = 1 THEN c.Month_Name END) AS Month1
, MAX(CASE WHEN m.rn = 2 THEN c.Month_Name END) AS Month2
, SUM(CASE WHEN m.rn = 1 THEN CAST(r.Revenue AS BIGINT) END) AS Revenue1
, SUM(CASE WHEN m.rn = 2 THEN CAST(r.Revenue AS BIGINT) END) AS Revenue2
FROM [Revenue Raw Data] r
JOIN CTE_MONTHS m ON m.Month_ID = r.Month_ID
LEFT JOIN yt_Calendar_lookup c ON c.Month_ID = r.Month_ID
) q;
```

Comment: Just as you have mentioned, I have added GROUP BY Month_Name to both the sub-queries, and I got the result exactly what I wanted. 
Thanks a lot.
I even shared my answer which is quiet different on how you have approached.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem.
As mentioned by one of the StackOverflow user, that all I had to add was **GROUP BY Month_Name** on both the sub-queries.

This is what I have done:

```
SELECT A.[Current Month], A.[Total Revenue for Current Month], B.[Previous Month], B.[Total Revenue for Previous Month],
A.[Total Revenue for current Month] - B.[Total Revenue for previous Month] AS 'Revenue Difference between current Month and previous Month'
FROM
(SELECT Month_Name AS 'Current Month', SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS 'Total Revenue for Current Month' 
FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN (SELECT MAX(Month_ID) FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
GROUP BY Month_Name
) A,
(SELECT Month_Name AS 'Previous Month', SUM(CAST(Revenue AS BIGINT)) AS 'Total Revenue for Previous Month'
FROM [Revenue Raw Data], yt_Calendar_lookup
WHERE [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID = yt_Calendar_lookup.Month_ID
AND [Revenue Raw Data].Month_ID IN (SELECT MAX(Month_ID) - 1 FROM [Revenue Raw Data])
GROUP BY Month_Name
) B
```

And it works perfectly.